# SPSecurity trimmed control not working

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, permissions

In SP2013, I want to hide the top bar for people who have only read permissions on the page. But the problem is, the top bar still shows no matter what. I have this

I have an account that just has read permissions. I remove the top bar by default, but this code is supposed to enable it if you have edit rights. So If I were to remove this code, and visit the page with that account, I actually don't see it. But if I add this code, and visit the page, I see the top bar, when I shouldn't because the account only has read permission. Somehow its getting permission. Does anyone know what's wrong?

Thanks

```
    <!-- show top black bar if you have permission -->
    <!--SPM:<SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl ID="SPSecurityTrimmedControlRibbon1" runat="server" PermissionContext="CurrentItem" PermissionsString="AddAndCustomizePages">-->
        <!--SPM:<SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="&#60;% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/_layouts/15/site_actions.css %&#62;" After="corev15.css" runat="server"/>-->
    <!--SPM:</SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>-->
```

Comment: You can hide the ribbon bar using JavaScript and just giving the condition according to your group that has read permissions and then hide the ribbon accordingly.

Comment: You can go through this link, https://sharepoint2020.wordpress.com/2013/10/30/hide-ribbon-from-users-with-read-permissions/

Answer (score 1):

I reviewed your code but i think your top bar control should be within SPSecurityTrimmedControl Tag not CssRegistration Tag.

Please go through this article  [Hide ribbon from users without Edit Permission](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zwsong/2010/04/29/how-to-hide-ribbon-from-users-without-edit-page-privilege/)

let me know if this is helpful or not

Thanks